If everything is an object in Python, how is the value of a primary type stored?
In Python, everything is an object. I'm fine with this. If I inspect a list or even a float, I can see there is a class associated with that data. But at the end of the day, if I make an value
x = 1, there has to be a value of 1 somewhere. If the class has an attribute "value" like this:
class int:
    self.__init__(value):
        self.value = value


value has to have some meaning. If it tried to make another int, we would end up in some infinite recursion.
Is there some sort of base type I'm missing? At some point, there must be a raw value to represent literals.

At that point the question becomes: which implementation? In CPython, for example, there's an array of bytes under there somewhere. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html

Ok, so if I'm understanding this right, when the literal 1 is stored, there is an external API call to C to represent the 1?

There is a value of 1, but it's buried in the implementation. In CPython, for example, you can see the definition of the int type in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c (not intobject.c for historical reasons). The comments go into detail about how it works, but the gist of it is that an integer is stored as an array of 30-bit values, each value serving as a "digit" in a very-high-base representation of the number.
The literal 1 itself refers to an instance of type int that the implementation creates as necessary. In CPython, at the C level, this is a value of type PyObject.
Put another way, the literal 1 is not an object; it's a syntactic construct that acts as a reference to an int object that represents the integer 1, just like x does after the assignment x = 1.

Thank you! This is what I was looking for
